# Do I have to edit/update/refresh service dependencies in visual studio if I add a new secret in key vault

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault

I've recently added a new secret to my Key vault in Azure.
Before publishing my project I want to be sure that no other action is needed.
Or should I edit/update/refresh service dependencies in visual studio if I add a new secret in key vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no need to update any reference, all you have to do is set the new secret uri in the environment variable, and the app will retrive the token from AD, pass to Key vault and it will retrieve the secret to your app.